# Why does this request return a string with bytes instead of JSON?

Tags: java, json, http, okhttp

I'm using the [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) library to make a GET request to a certain endpoint that returns JSON data. But it returns a String type with bytes instead of JSON.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<OTHER CLASSES REDACTED>

public static class GetDrivesRequest {
 private final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

 public Response run(String offset, HashMap < String, String > headers) throws IOException {
  if (offset == null || offset == "") offset = "0";

  HttpUrl mUrl = new HttpUrl.Builder()
   .scheme("https")
   .host("www.waze.com")
   .addPathSegment("row-Descartes-live")
   .addPathSegment("app")
   .addPathSegment("Archive")
   .addPathSegment("List")
   .addQueryParameter("minDistance", "1000")
   .addQueryParameter("count", "50")
   .addQueryParameter("offset", offset)
   .build();

  Request.Builder requestB = new Request.Builder()
   .url(mUrl);

  for (Map.Entry < String, String > entry: headers.entrySet()) {
   String key = entry.getKey();
   String value = entry.getValue();

   if (key != "" && value != "") {
    requestB.addHeader(key, value);
   }
  }

  Request request = requestB.build();

  Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
  return response;
 }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String GET_CSRF_URL = "https://www.waze.com/login/get";
  String SESSION_URL = "https://www.waze.com/login/create";
  String SESSION_LIST_URL = "https://www.waze.com/row-Descartes-live/app/Archive/List";
  String SESSON_DATA_URL = "https://www.waze.com/row-Descartes-live/app/Archive/SessionGPS";

  // ===[ 1 - Get CSRF token ]===============
  // ----------------------------------------
  GetCsrfRequest getCsrf = new GetCsrfRequest();
  Response req = getCsrf.run(GET_CSRF_URL);

  // ===[ 2 - Login ]===============
  // -------------------------------
  HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<String, String>();
  cookies.put("editor_env", "row");
  cookies.put("_web_session", req.headers().toString().split(":")[6].split("=")[1].split(";")[0]);
  cookies.put("_csrf_token", req.headers().toString().split(":")[9].split("=")[1].split(";")[0]);

  HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
  headers.put("Accept", "*/*");
  headers.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
  headers.put("Accept-Language", "nl,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,de;q=0.2,fr;q=0.2,it;q=0.2");
  headers.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
  headers.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
  headers.put("Cookie", cookies.toString());
  headers.put("Host", "www.waze.com");
  headers.put("Origin", "https://www.waze.com/");
  headers.put("Referer", "https://www.waze.com/");
  headers.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36");
  headers.put("X-CSRF-Token", req.headers().toString().split(":")[9].split("=")[1].split(";")[0]);
  headers.put("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

  PostRequest postLogin = new PostRequest();
  Response req2 = postLogin.run(SESSION_URL, "<REDACTED>", "<REDACTED>", headers);

  // ===[ 3 - Get list of drives ]===============
  // --------------------------------------------
  HashMap<String, String> cookies2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
  cookies2.put("editor_env", "row");
  cookies2.put("_web_session", req2.headers().toString().split(":")[6].split("=")[1].split(";")[0]);
  cookies2.put("_csrf_token", req2.headers().toString().split(":")[9].split("=")[1].split(";")[0]);

  HashMap<String, String> headers2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
  headers2.put("Accept", "*/*");
  headers2.put("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
  headers2.put("Accept-Language", "nl,en");
  headers2.put("Connection", "keep-alive");
  headers2.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
  headers2.put("Cookie", cookies2.toString());
  headers2.put("Host", "www.waze.com");
  headers2.put("Origin", "https://www.waze.com/");
  headers2.put("Referer", "https://www.waze.com/");
  headers2.put("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36");
  headers2.put("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");

  GetDrivesRequest drivesRequest = new GetDrivesRequest();
  Response req3 = drivesRequest.run("0", headers2);
  System.out.println(req3.body().string());
}
```

This seems to return a String filled with bytes:

```
����n7��e�:�I��9����؋X�#�U@л���
�F��IR�9��js�����ϤN��Y�U`�`��\-$��čj�]���A�Y-�;
��8y�l5�����q��/4��|sxw��>��D��5r�2���<O!�-���]&g�2�vj����C���,�v��cM�0[�lD�uO���;��i�0�"��fR�>���ϭJ�ĳf�zF  ������w��F��4FI�ԫV���1������
dGQ��8����56�4b���X6y�]8��cF)j8Ⱦ�p��    ĺ��N栙l�IT��K�-Y�����ϚA�1���c���K��1u�����
�E���?���8��P_��K�����y�Kֲ��3y
��J�3�oc�$��h#��Ls���k7��s�xp}Y)b�I�sၧ>���&���2=klƧ�t�1G����5p�q)`�BL��X�̎=�%�渖�{�k��8��g�V��Ê�ZwPPKEZp�+�o��ɨ�0cf�`/�d��&Cǌy�DB��}���Ƃ��f����Pw���W5��Z�0Y'��|�qCM8�}$�96����
wZ�q}�����.��]>���H������5�TL��{_{f�S�P�3;[���`ˤ) ��F30BP�_
BČn{
�;��g$�͌3b�/���<w
q��"�2�fU�5p�q�Şr����"�8��j�Ůт��S~��7��ol���:�������G#
```

Am I doing something wrong? `req.body().string()` and `req2.body().string()` do return the correct data.

Comment: What do you get in `req3.body().contentType().toString()` ?

Comment: @PeterMmm I get `application/json`

Comment: Have You tried manually invoking this address with the same headers? 
You can use various tools to do that, ie. Postman (a chrome extension).

Maybe it's the server that returns wrong values?

Comment: IMO, your server has responsed zipped/compressed data

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, any updates?